# How do i create a countdown timer in ModalView after pressing a button?

Tags: kivy

I am trying to create a modalview with a timer in it. Upon pressing the "begin" button, a modal view should appear and the countdown should start. However, I am getting an valueerror message. ValueError: TimerView.timer has an invalid format (got main.TimerView object at 0x0000017AD40D6180>>>).May I know which part of the code is wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition, WipeTransition, NoTransition, SlideTransition
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.clock import Clock

class TimerView(ModalView):
    number = NumericProperty(15)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background = "transparent_image.png"
        self.background_color = [1/3,1/3,1/3,0.8]
        self.auto_dismiss = False
        self.size_hint = (None,None)
        self.size = (150,50)
        timer_countdown = MDLabel(font_style = 'H1', theme_text_color = 'Primary',
                                  text = str(self.number), halign = 'center',
                                  text_color = (1,1,1,1), size_hint_y = None)
        self.add_widget(timer_countdown)

    def decrement_time(self, dt):
        self.number -= 1

    def start(self,*args):
        self.timer = Clock.schedule_interval(self.decrement_time, 1)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.timer)

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class BeginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.view = TimerView()

    def open_view(self):
        self.view.bind(on_open=self.view.start)
        self.view.open()

main_widget_kv = ('''
#: import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect

MyScreenManager:
    BeginScreen:

<BeginScreen>:
    begin_button:begin_button
    name: "begin"
    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgb: .1, .1, .1
    FloatLayout:
        id: begin_layout
        Button:
            id: begin_button
            text: 'Begin'
            font_size: 24
            on_press: app.root.open_view()
            size_hint: (.4,.25)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.2}
            color: [0,0,0,1]


''')

class TestApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        main_widget = Builder.load_string(main_widget_kv)
        return main_widget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Your main problem is using `self.timer` in two different places for two different purposes. It cannot be both a number and a `ClockEvent`.

Comment: Hi @JohnAnderson, thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the code, but the label doesn't change overtime. However, if I print self.number every second, it is in fact changing. Just the label won't update itself. What else should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `text` of a `Label` in python code, it uses the value at that time, and will not change automatically. If you do the same thing in `kv`, it will update automatically (provided that the `text` references a `Property`). So just changing `self.number` has no effect on your `timer_countdown` `Label`.

So, you need to update that `text` explicitly. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
class TimerView(ModalView):
    number = NumericProperty(15)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background = "transparent_image.png"
        self.background_color = [1/3,1/3,1/3,0.8]
        self.auto_dismiss = False
        self.size_hint = (None,None)
        self.size = (150,50)
        self.timer_countdown = MDLabel(font_style = 'H1', theme_text_color = 'Primary',
                                  text = str(self.number), halign = 'center',
                                  text_color = (1,1,1,1), size_hint_y = None)
        self.add_widget(self.timer_countdown)

    def decrement_time(self, dt):
        self.number -= 1
        # self.timer_countdown.text = str(self.number)

    def on_number(self, instance, value):
        self.timer_countdown.text = str(value)

    def start(self,*args):
        self.t = Clock.schedule_interval(self.decrement_time, 1)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.t)
```

A reference to the `MDLabel` is kept in `self.timer_countdown` and the `on_number()` method gets executed whenever `number` changes, and just updates the `MDLabel`. Note that you can also do the update by just uncommenting the line:

```
# self.timer_countdown.text = str(self.number)
```

In that case, `number` does not need to be a `Property`, and the `on_number()` method is not needed.